# Подключение к базе данных firebird на C# WPF

Tags: c#, firebird

Подскажите, как можно подключиться к бд firebird на C#

```
    ds = new DataSet("session");
conStr = "server=localhost; User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; port =3050; Database=E:\\1.fdb;";
                fbDa = new FbDataAdapter("select * from pol;", conStr);
                comBuilder = new FbCommandBuilder(fbDa);
                fbDa.Fill(ds, "pol");
```

Comment: Что именно не работает в приведённом коде? Распишите подробнее. Какие ошибки выдаёт?

Comment: А причём тут WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант №1 (простой).** Скачать клиентские сборки (`FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient`) через NuGet. Далее по [инструкции](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/c-rabotaem-s-firebird-25-iz-visual-studio-2010-3034). Есть ещё подробная [инструкция](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278405/) по работе с FireBird в EntityFramework.

**Вариант №2 (сложный).** Через ODBC (требуется установка IBPhoenix).
Пример строки подключения (к локальному серверу):

```
DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey; DBNAME=C:\database\myData.fdb;
```

Comment: Сборки скачаны, но на одном компьютере подключение, на другом не подключается

Comment: Попробую поиграть в угадайку. Программа на обоих компах подключается к `localhost`? Если да, то нет ничего удивительного, что на другом компе она не работает. Если нет смотрите настройки FireBird, сети, файрфола и т.д.

Comment: да к localhost.